# Two dates/Periods in same select statement and return data for each period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok, I have a working piece of code that gets data related to dollars view, by location, operation, exceptions and finally spending. This is done by FYPeriod. Lets say this returned FYPeriod 11702 which is August 2016. I also want it to return on the same row FYPeriod 11602 which is August 2015. I have tried adding another join and simply doing a (FYPeriod - 100) but of course this returned nothing. Here is the working code that returns the FYPeriod.

```
SELECT dbo.fiscalmonthyearstring(f.FYPeriod) As MonthYear, f.FYPeriod, c.SYSTEMPLANT, e.SpendingAcct, 
c.DOLLARS, f.Data AS Units, d.exceptions, f.PLActivity
    FROM [vw_TotalDollars] c 
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[location] b ON b.PlantId = c.SYSTEMPLANT
    LEFT JOIN [Operations] f ON f.FYPeriod = c.PST 
AND f.location = b.location
    JOIN [dbo].[aexceptions] d ON b.PlantId = d.Id
AND d.acc = c.ACCN
AND exceptions IN ('Z2', 'X2'  , 'Z7' , 'X7')
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Spending] e ON e.SpendingId = d.SpendingId
    WHERE f.PLActivity = 'Total Produced'
```

I hope I have explained this correctly and if not I will try to do so.

[image: Current output]

Comment: why is `[Operations] f ` a `left join` when you are using `f` in the `where` basically making it an `inner join` ? -- why is `[dbo].[location] b` a `left join` when you are using it in the `inner join` for `[dbo].[aexceptions] d` ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Can you provide sample data from your tables? Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: MSSMS is the DBMS I am using.

Comment: I have attached a current output, what I need is two more columns that show the previous FYPeriod's DOLLARS and UNITS @EdwardRusu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of your filtering is necessary to also get the prior year data, we could wrap up your current query in a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) so that we can reference it against itself like so:

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      o.fyperiod
    , td.systemplant
    , s.SpendingAcct
    , td.dollars
    , o.[Data] as Units
    , ae.exceptions
    , o.plactivity
  from [vw_TotalDollars] td
    inner join [Operations] o
      on o.fyperiod   = td.pst 
     and o.plactivity = 'Total Produced'
    left join [dbo].[location] l
      on l.PlantId  = td.systemplant
     and l.location = o.location
    left join [dbo].[aexceptions] ae
      on ae.Id  = td.systemplant
     and ae.acc = td.accn
     and ae.exceptions in ('Z2','X2','Z7','X7')
    left join [dbo].[Spending] s
      on s.SpendingId = ae.SpendingId
)
select
    cte.FyPeriod
  --, MonthYear = dbo.fiscalmonthyearstring(cte.fyperiod)
  , cte.SystemPlan
  , cte.SpendingAcct
  , cte.Dollars
  , cte.Units
  , cte.Exceptions
  , cte.Plactivity
  --, pyMonthYear = dbo.fiscalmonthyearstring(py.fyperiod)
  , pyDollars   = py.Dollars
  , pyUnits     = py.Units
from cte
  left join cte as py 
    on py.fyperiod     = cte.fyperiod-100
   and py.systemplant  = cte.systemplant
   and py.exceptions   = cte.exceptions
   and py.SpendingAcct = cte.SpendingAcct
```

note: your scalar function `dbo.fiscalmonthyearstring()` would perform better if rewritten as an inline table-valued function.

inline table-valued functions vs scalar functions reference:

- [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)

Comment: if I change the joins from left, my query no longer outputs anything. Just runs until it times out. On a side note thank you for the links, the Bad Habits to kick was an eye opener...

Comment: @Jeremy I have updated the query and moved the joins a bit, since you have `WHERE f.PLActivity = 'Total Produced'`, that is essentially making the join to `Operations` an `inner join` and I have changed `aexceptions` to join using `vw_TotalDollars.SystemPlant` instead of `Location.PlantId`. Try running it without the `cte` to see if you get your original results, and try running it without using your function `dbo.fiscalmonthyearstring()` as well to see how that impacts performance.

Comment: These changes worked on the main query. But with the addition of the cte, it is replicating the main data and not the cte data. I can attach a screen shot if you need.

Comment: On further investigation, all data is repeating except for pyDollars which changes per row.

Comment: @Jeremy you need to modify the self join condition for the `cte` so that you get the correct match for py. Without seeing sample tables and data all I can do is guess. -- I updated the code to only get prior year dollars when the systemplant, exceptions, and spendingAcct aren't `null` and match.

Comment: Thank you so much, I found the join issue and I really appreciate all your help. And thank you for the information in the links. I will defiantly apply what I have learned to improve my code!